# How to use vb6 copymemory in c#?

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

This is vb6 codes:

```
Dim i    As Long
CopyMemory fkey(0), pass(0), 4& * i
```

I know `CopyMemory(destination, source, length)`. But I dont know how to implement it in c#.

I have one empty `long` array, and one `byte` array with values.

Source : `byte` array.

Destination : `long` array.

How do i use `CopyMemory` in c# for these two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're copying from and to arrays you can just you `Buffer.BlockCopy`.

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(pass, 0, fkey, 0, 4)
```

This will treat the arrays as byte arrays, so the index is in bytes, not in the size of the data-type.

You can learn more online: [MSDN Online Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)